# fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog() tooo slow and hang when choosing lot of files

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I choose about eight-hundred image files, and each has a 5 MB size using the following code:

```
List<File> flist = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(label.getScene().getWindow());
```

When I click open, the `filechooser` and the main window freeze (and do not respond).

What should I do to ameliorate this problem? (I don't want to use Swing.)

My code is for adding image file names list to a tableView. Not for loading image. After running this code, I am getting output in the terminal:

```
Total Files added: 800.
```

But `filechooser` and the main window freeze (and do not respond)

```
public void addImage()
{
    int i = 0;
    List<File> list = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(label.getScene().getWindow());
    if (list != null) {
        for (File f : list) {
            data.add( new ImgInfo(1 + data.size() + "", f));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total Files added: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably should look for an alternative method for opening such large number of files?

Comment: What is actually taking the time? I can use a `FileChooser` to retrieve a list of about 10,000 files without it hanging the UI. Are you trying to load each file into an `Image`? You probably need to post a little more code and show where the UI is actually hanging.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working on an image processing project where you don't actually need to view all the input images. I would suggest the following approach if all the files are in a single folder:

```
public void filesInFolder(File folder) {
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
            // Open File Here
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to choose multiple files from a folder, not all files.

Comment: The if condition in the loop can be modified to choose the specific files you want to open.

Answer (score 0):

[`fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenMultipleDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) does not hang and is not too slow when I use it.

Here is a sample application I used.  Choosing a few thousand files and displaying their names in a [ListView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) took less than a second. Test environment: JavaFX 8u20, Windows 7, 6 year old PC.

[image: filelist]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class SelectedFileInfoViewer extends Application {
    @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final ListView<File> chosenFilesView = new ListView<>();

        final Button chooseFilesButton = new Button("Choose Files");
        chooseFilesButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            List<File> files = new FileChooser().showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
            if (files != null) {
                chosenFilesView.getItems().setAll(files);
            }
        });

        final Label numFilesChosen = new Label();
        numFilesChosen.textProperty().bind(
                Bindings.concat(
                        "Number of Files: ",
                        Bindings.size(
                                chosenFilesView.getItems()
                        ).asString()
                )
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                10,
                chooseFilesButton,
                chosenFilesView,
                numFilesChosen
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: This code also hangs for me. i am using Java8 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: after waiting a long time , its getting ok. is this bug of javafx filechooser in linux.

Comment: As your issue appears to be environment specific, you might want to log an issue in the JavaFX issue tracker: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/ so that the JavaFX developers can investigate it, when you log the issue you can refer back to this StackOverflow answer.

Comment: for me it is also hanging.... I was trying to do my stuff multithreaded, but then I realized it was the DirectoryChooser

Comment: @El Mac log a bug report at: http://bugreport.java.com make sure that you include your full environment details in the bug report (OS/Java Version/Graphics Card/Graphics Card Driver Version).

Comment: FWIW, this still code still works fine for me on OS X 10.9.5, Java 8u66, 2014 Retina MacBook Pro 15, Nvidia GeForce GT 750M.